# unix - get substring of a file name

Tags: string, shell, unix, filenames, cut

If I have a folder called myfiles/ which has a bunch of python files in it, in a shell script like the following:

```
for k in myfiles/*.py
do
// code here?
done
```

How do I print for each k a string that's just `--name-of-file--.py` ? 
If I do

```
echo $k
```

as is, it prints `myfiles/--name-of-file--.py`

I'm very new to shell scripting, but it seems like the cut function attempts to cut the contents of the file and not just the file name (and I don't really know how to use cut).

To be clear, I'd like to know how to get rid of the folder name when printing.

Answer (score 2):

```
basename "$k"
```

Or if you want to avoid spawning so many processes, this is more efficient:

```
echo ${k##*/}
```